# Append dot before each letters

Tags: python

I want to add a point before each letter.
Unfortunately, the point is after each letter. How to insert the point before each letter?

```
myText = str(input())
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
result = ''
for letter in myText:
    if letter not in vowels:
        result = result + letter
        for i in result:
            result = result + '.'
            break

print(result.lower())
```

Comment: what is the vowels aspect? do you want to remove vowels from the input or only append `.`s after vowels or only append after non-vowel letters

Comment: i want to remove the vowels and append " . "  before each letter and finally have all letters in lower case.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all the relevant information about lowercasing and removing vowels. Ideally also add some sample input and output.

Comment: Please give at least one example.

Answer (score 2):

A shorter and faster solution relying on the power of [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
import re
my_text = "sample"
re.sub(r"[aeiou]*([^aeiou])[aeiou]*", r".\1", my_text.lower())
```

This reads: “delete vowels, and prefix each remaining letter with a dot”.

Answer (score 0):

Removing all vowels and append "." before each letter.

```
myText = "sample"
vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']
result = ''
for letter in myText:
    if letter not in vowels:
        result = result + '.' + letter

print(result.lower())
# .s.m.p.l
```

Answer (score 0):

Fian's answer is probably the best one. Here's my attempt:

```
text = 'audfijsdfmsomlasn'
vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U'}

result = ''

for letter in text:
    if letter in vowels:
        result += '.'
    result += letter

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
import re
myText = "sample"
result = '.' + '.'.join(list(re.sub('[aeiou]', "", myText, flags=re.I)))
print(result)
```

Explanation:

- `re.sub` removes the not required letters (case insensitive = `re.I`)
- `list` makes the string an array of characters
- `join` places a dot in between
- `'.' +` adds the missing dot in front of the first character

Answer (score 0):

```
string = input()
vowels = ['a', 'A', 'i', 'I', 'o', 'O', 'u', 'U', 'e', 'E']
translation = string.maketrans({i: '' for i in vowels})
string = string.translate(translation)
result = ''
for letter in string:
    result = result + '.' + letter
print(result.lower())
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.